# Unable to get particular output in a file

Tags: java, file-io

```
File outputFile2 = new File("money2.txt");
    BufferedWriter outData2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile2));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(ts[i].getMoney());
        outData2.write("TESTING");
        outData2.write(ts[i].getMoney());
        outData2.newLine();
    }
    outData2.close();
```

This is my code. In my console I get

```
20000
10000
10000
4000
```

Which is exactly what I want in my file. But instead, I get this in `money2.txt`:

```
TESTING?
TESTING?
TESTING?
TESTING?
```

*(Testing is there for debugging purposes)*

I can't figure out how to debug this. My file is being written to correctly (since 'TESTING' is getting printed. My array is being read from correctly (since output to the console is correct.

What is going wrong?

Comment: what does `ts[i].getMoney()` return?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect `ts[i].getMoney()` is an `int` and as BufferedWriter is a low level text interface it assumes you are writing a codePoint character i.e. `(char) 20000` and `(char) 10000` which appears as `?` as its unknown for the character encoding you are using.

Try the following instead with PrintWriter

```
File outputFile2 = new File("money2.txt");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile2)));
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println(ts[i].getMoney());
    out.println("TESTING " + ts[i].getMoney());
}
out.close();
```

Comment: Great! Works now. Any particular advantage of using BufferedWriter ever? Or should I go ahead with using PrintWriter always?

Comment: PrintWriter is easier to use. If you need buffering, you can use both.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.toString()` after `ts[i].getMoney()`  and if not OK use `Integer.toString(ts[i])`

Comment: Which calls `Integer.toString(ts[i])` ;)